# Laravel Task Scheduling not running commands

Tags: php, laravel

In my app/Console/Kernel.php, I have set my code as

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->job(new Refresher);
    }
```

When I run the `php artisan schedule:run` command, I get the `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` message. I'm not sure if I am missing out on anything, I have tried adding the `->everyMinute()`, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a queued job. The queue should run on its own. However if you want to start the queue on your own use the command:

```
php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

Queued job, like scheduled tasks, should have a frequency option chained after the job method. Add it to your code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new Refresher)->everyMinute();
}
```

Note: the Refresher class must respect a specific class structure.You can find it in the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#class-structure ( I don't know the Laravel version you're working on so i posted the 5.8 docs. Just change the version to the one you're using in the URL)

If you need to create a simple task you can simply change the code to:

```
$schedule->call(new Refresher)->everyMinute();
```